# Is it ). or .)?

Tags: writing

I had a discussion about this recently: do you write ). or .)?

For example:

"Websites can be assigned to application pools, all application pools containing specific settings for applications (allowing you to isolate websites)."

Or:

"Websites can be assigned to application pools, all application pools containing specific settings for applications (allowing you to isolate websites.)"

Comment: First one. The punctatuation could be inside if the whole sentences was in between parenthesis: "(Websites can be .../...applications –allowing you to isolate websites.)"

Comment: Here are two examples from "Authors:" (N&Q) >
>  Exact dates should take this form: 16 May 1913 (without comma). Let
 AD precede the year, but let BC follow (small caps, no full stops).